# Plugin used to expand - collapse text

Tags: plugin-recommendation

Do you know which plugin was used to expand collapse text like in this page?

http://www.hilyamedia.com/resources

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they're not using a plugin, it's built-in to their theme. However, the script seems to be [ddaccordion](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ddaccordion.htm), so you should be able to get it working on your own site.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a similar effect with jQuery UI's Accordion function.  There is a plugin ([WP UI](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-ui/))which extends the visual editor and gives you shortcodes to handle inserting the accordions.  You will need to style the accordions yourself, but you will need to do that no matter what.